# Showing rendered Latex during review

Tags: feature-request

At this moment, there is a suggested edit to [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/9957/6986) in the review queue. When seen from the review pane, the edits display the Latex code used to render the final output. As someone who doesn't know Latex all that well, I find this annoying, especially when the edits are solely in regard to the Latex code.

Would it be possible to make a change to the review process so the review pane can display the final result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of a possible duplicate: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1831/render-mathjax-in-review-queues?rq=1

Comment: @HDE226868 Interesting. It keeps coming up, but never gets resolved...

Comment: Yeah, that's frustrating.  This looks like a dupe so I'm going to mark it as such; if it's not, please edit to disambiguate.  Thanks.